# Function action on tkinter button and results on label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this function and I need to build an interface for it.
It's a function that is searching some data in the log file.
This data needs to printed into Label.
1. Data (int ) needs to be user input.
2. Value from user input will be searched in the log file
3. Results from the log needs to printed on label.

Thank you for support.
I'm  new here! So hello to everyone.

Namaste!
[This is the progress-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5saAb.jpg)
Please see below the code:

```
    def searcher():
        imei = input("Insert imei: ")
        log = reversed(list(open("C:/test.log")))

        if len(imei) == 15:
            for line in log:
               if imei in line:
                    if ("[S/W Upgrade]") in line:
                        print (line,"S/W upgrade found in LOG- OK to close the JOB")
                    elif ("SVC Connection") in line:
                        print(" SVC connexion only FOUND! Please connect device again for S/W Upgrade!")
                    else:
                        print(line,"FAIL")
                    break
            else:
                print("IMEI not found in LOG FILE - please connect device to FENRIR for S/W upgrade")
        else:
            print("Wrong IMEI number- please check your input!")

        return()

    searcher()


Please see below my progress:

import tkinter as tk


class ImeiApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Check IMEI", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(self,command=searcher)
def searcher():
    global line
    global searcher
    imei = tk.Entry
    log = reversed(list(open('C:/test.log','r')))
    if len(imei) == 15:
        for line in log:
           if imei in line:
                if ("[S/W Upgrade]") in line:
                    print (line,"S/W upgrade found in LOG- OK to close the JOB")
                elif ("SVC Connection") in line:
                    print(" SVC connexion only FOUND! Please connect device again for S/W Upgrade!")
                else:
                    print(line,"FAIL")
                break
        else:
            print("IMEI not found in LOG FILE - please connect device to FENRIR for S/W upgrade")
    else:
        print("Wrong IMEI number- please check your input!")

    return()

app = ImeiApp()
app.mainloop()
self.button.pack()
self.entry.pack()
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Is there a specific problem you're having? Have you worked through a tkinter tutorial?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question titles, as well. "Python 3 tkinter" unfortunately doesn't tell the community what you need or how to best answer your question.

Comment: I just added my progress. I have the button - and the entry window - but i miss the label and the button action ( function is not triggered when button is pressed )

Comment: I don't think your line `imei = tk.Entry` does what you were hoping for.  I think you need something like `imei = self.entry.get()`.  See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: thanks jcfollower :) I will try more and post back! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be that your button does not execute your `searcher` function as you expected.

The code for your button looks like this:

```
self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Check IMEI", command=self.on_button)
```

While the function it's supposed to execute is this:

```
def on_button(self):
    self.button = tk.Button(self.root,command=searcher)
```

That means that on pressing the button, you create a new button with a different command (`searcher`) and assign it to your original button. This happens when clicking on your button for the first time; clicking on it for a second time, the "new" button will look for the `searcher` function, which does not exist - it is outside of the scope of the class.

My solution is to

- include the `searcher` function in your `ImeiApp` class
- drop the on_button function altogether
- assign `self.searcher` as the command for your button

Here we go:

```
class ImeiApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.button = tk.Button(
            self.root, text="Check IMEI", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def on_button(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, command=searcher)

    def searcher(self):
        ...
```

Notice that I made some changes to your class' `__init__` function. Instead of using your class itself as the main window, I generated a main window called `root` and put the button and the entry widget in there.

Concerning your code in general: As [jcfollower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856070/jcfollower) pointed out in the comments, you should check out [effbot's introduction to tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) and maybe the [Python docs on Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) for more information on how tkinter is used.